# React API Reference

Tags: reactjs, axios

[image]

The "list" is API_Call from the "Axios.get".

I want to check the API "src" Empty or not.

How can I check for this.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You'll find it easier to get help by copying and pasting the actual code instead of posting an image of it.

Comment: <Card src=""> comes from the API.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could use conditional logic like this, to render either the image for  `result.volumeInfo.imageLinks.thumbnail`, or some other fallback image if `result.volumeInfo.imageLinks.thumbnail` is undefined?

So, somthing like the following:

```html
<Card key={result.id}
  hoverable
  style={{ width:240 }}
  cover={ () => {

    const cardImage = result.volumeInfo.imageLinks.thumbnail

    // If result.volumeInfo.imageLinks.thumbnail is defined, render
    // image with it, otherwise rendering some other fallback image
    return (cardImage ? 
      <img alt="example" src={ cardImage } /> :
      <img alt="example" src="/some-empty-image.jpg" />)
  }} >    

  <Meta title={result.volumeInfo.title} />
</Card>
```

Comment: @SeanKim you're welcome - glad I could help! Please consider accepting this answer if it's been useful to you :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
Call a get API using axios and check response.
// Make a request for a list
 axios.get('URL path')
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
    //put ur condition code here if exits or not whatever u want
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

Comment: Yeah I know how to do this. I mean,  how can check the API params Empty or not.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
src={result.volumeInfo.title == "" ? "empty-src" : result.volumeInfo.title }
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<Card key={result.id}
  hoverable
  style={{ width:240 }}
  cover={ () => {

    const cardImage = result.volumeInfo.imageLinks.thumbnail

    // If result.volumeInfo.imageLinks.thumbnail is defined, render
    // image with it, otherwise rendering some other fallback image
    return (cardImage ? 
      <img alt="example" src={ cardImage } /> :
      <img alt="example" src="/some-empty-image.jpg" />)
  }} >    

  <Meta title={result.volumeInfo.title} />
</Card>
```

Comment: <Card 
                cover = {
                        result.volumeInfo.imageLinks.thumbnail ? <img src={result.volumeInfo.imageLinks.thumbnail}/>: 
                        <img src=""/>
                    } 
                >
This is working. Thanks for your example~!!